# Processar no servidor e retornar em um Input PHP

Tags: php, html

Olá, eu estou fazendo uma calculadora em **PHP** e **HTML**, e eu queria que quando o usuário apertasse no submit, seja calculado no servidor, e o resultado retornasse no Input resultado, se você não entendeu, vou tentar explicar de uma forma mais básica:

Usuário Adiciona os números no primeiro e segundo campo de texto (Input) o resultado será calculado e irá aparecer no **terceiro campo**.

Queria fazer isso usando **PHP**, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Qual a dúvida? Tem um problema com código específico?

Comment: Sim, eu queria saber como fazer isso

Comment: É uma tarefa relativamente simples, já tentou algo? Está com algum problema em um código que já desenvolveu ou é dúvida de como fazer mesmo? No segundo caso, recomendo dar uma revisada nos conhecimentos que você possui sobre a linguagem, quando estiver melhor acostumado, daí você tenta fazer algo

Comment: Eu estou aprendendo PHP, a minha professora ainda não me explicou sobre isso, mas se é tão fácil assim, vou pesquisar

Comment: Só um lembrete: É fácil se você já tem um base da linguagem, caso não saiba nada, recomendo aprender mais um pouco e depois tentar fazer

Comment: Mas você poderia me falar qual comando eu usaria?

Comment: O que você quer fazer deu pra entender perfeitamente, o que não dá pra entender é em qual parte você está com a dificuldade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que uma forma bem simples de fazer isso seria (caso você não conheça muito bem ainda a linguagem), utilizar o [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html) com apache para executar os arquivos.

Caso utilize o xampp, depois de instalado, basta adicionar seus arquivos e projetos no diretório C:\xampp\htdocs\ e dar um "start" no apache.

Bem vamos lá.

Crie um arquivo html que terá o seu formulário, como por exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
     <form method="POST" action="calcular.php">
        Primeiro número:<br>
        <input name="primeiro" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
        Segundo número:<br>
        <input name="segundo" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
        Operacao:<br>
        <select name="operacao">
          <option value="+">Somar</option>
          <option value="-">Subtrair</option>
          <option value="/">Dividir</option>
          <option value="*">Multiplicar</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calcular"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bom o atributo "action" do form está apontando para outro arquivo, no caso um arquivo chamado calcular.php é nele que será feito toda a lógica da calculadora.

```
<?php
$primeiro = $_POST['primeiro'];
$segundo = $_POST['segundo'];
$operacao = $_POST['operacao'];

$resultado = 0;
if ($operacao == "+") {
    $resultado = $primeiro + $segundo;
} else if ($operacao == "-") {
    $resultado = $primeiro + $segundo;
} else if ($operacao == "*") {
    $resultado = $primeiro * $segundo;
} else if ($operacao == "/") {
    $resultado = $primeiro / $segundo;
}
echo $resultado;
?>
```

Para adicionar o resultado a um input na mesma tela só utilizando **HTML**, **PHP**, uma solução seria criar apenas um arquivo .php, por exemplo calcular.php e nele você terá tanto a lógica da calculadora quanto o formulário html, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
$primeiro = $_POST['primeiro'];
$segundo= $_POST['segundo'];
$operacao = $_POST['operacao'];
$resultado = 0;
if ($operacao == "+") {
    $resultado = $primeiro + $segundo;
} else if ($operacao == "-") {
    $resultado = $primeiro - $segundo;
} else if ($operacao == "*") {
    $resultado = $primeiro * $segundo;
} else if ($operacao == "/") {
    $resultado = $primeiro / $segundo;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
     <form method="POST" action="">
        Primeiro número:<br>
        <input name="primeiro" type="text" value="<?= $primeiro ?>" size="30"/><br>
        Segundo número:<br>
        <input name="segundo" type="text" value="<?= $segundo ?>" size="30"/><br>
        Operacao:<br>
        <select name="operacao">
          <option value="+">Somar</option>
          <option value="-">Subtrair</option>
          <option value="/">Dividir</option>
          <option value="*">Multiplicar</option>
        </select><br>
        Resultado:<br>
        <input name="resultado" type="text" value="<?= $resultado ?>" size="30"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calcular"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Mas vale lembrar que exitem outras soluções como por exemplo utilizar ajax, js etc..
Se você estiver apenas no começo do mundo da programação aconselho a ir pelo simples e ir aprendendo passo a passo as coisas, conforme você for se sentindo mais a vontade pode experimentar outras soluções.

Mas o que foi alterado nesse exemplo comparado ao primeiro?
Vamos lá,
removi o valor do atributo "action" do formulário, pois ele apontará para a mesma página, ou seja será redirecionado ao clicar em "Calcular" para o calular.php novamente, porém como você terá preenchido os dados, é possível pegarmos via **POST** ou **GET**. E dessa forma eu consigo exibir o resultado através das tags  no formulário HTML.

Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: Muito bom! Mas teria como eu colocar o $resultado dentro de um input no HTML?

Comment: Oláa, siim, só utilizando o HMTL e PHP existe uma forma, por exemplo utilizando o mesmo arquivo, dessa forma você manda o resultado para a própria página, vou postar um exemplo :)

Comment: Certo, estou no aguardo! Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: @KarenVicente recomendo dar uma lida [nesta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/53279) publicação sobre as imagens

Comment: @KarenVicente foi de grande ajuda! Mas um erro persiste, no input resultado, aparece: <?= $total ?>, ou seja, o código, e não o resultado :( 
O que posso fazer?

Comment: @DetetiveVirtual você poderia mandar o seu código completo?
Já tentou assim?: <?php echo $total; ?>

Comment: Aqui está o código https://pastebin.com/ePBaj6SS

Comment: @DetetiveVirtual
Olá!!
bom eu acho que o problema está no <select>, você deve passar um atributo chamato "value" para cada option

Ex:
<option value="Somar">+</option>, desta maneira basta utilizar o atributo "name" para pegar o valor selecionado $_POST["select"];:

Comment: Certo, vou mudar isso

Comment: Infelizmente, o erro persiste :(

Comment: Mas tudo bem, embora eu gostaria muito de fazer desse jeito, eu fiz de uma outra maneira, obrigado mesmo assim!